# Python Minutes to HH:MM Conversion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to determine the best way to add a column to my pandas dataframe that converts total minutes (which is in int format) into HH:MM format. I am aware that the easiest way to do this is with datetime, but I can't seem to figure out the best way to convert the data from a Series to make this happen.

Here is the error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: Series
```

Code (e.g. 346.0):

```
df['minutes_asleep_hm'] = str(timedelta(minutes=df['minutes_asleep']))[:-3]
```

Type:

```
Name: minutes_asleep, dtype: float64
```

Comment: for pandas series, you should use [Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html#pandas-timedelta) subclass within pandas itself, Also, for more better help it would be better if you include the sample series you are trying to use!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert integer series to timedelta in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519536/convert-integer-series-to-timedelta-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series is essentially a list of values. You need to use a [*map*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function which applies a given operation to every element in the series and returns the result of this function as a series.

```
df['minutes_asleep_hm'] = df['minutes_asleep'].map(lambda x: str(timedelta(minutes=x))[:-3], na_action='ignore')
```

Notes:

1. The variable `x`, though undescriptive, is pretty standard for lambdas and is used here to keep the line short. It represents the current series value that the function is operating on.
2. A lambda isn't required. Any standard function will do, but a lambda was used as it's fairly standard and is a convienient one liner.

Comment: This is great and what I was looking for, but what should be modified to the data to handle NaN or null values? I received this error `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Comment: @cphill: According to the docs, you can use the parameter `na_action`. I've updated my answer to include it.