# Conversion of integer values into days in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, types, timedelta

How do I convert the datatype of a column from integer to timedelta days format? I tried doing it but got the following error.

```
new_monthly5['APPROVED LEAVES'] = new_monthly5['APPROVED 
LEAVES']+timedelta(days=1)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timedelta'
```

Also, I tried it another way but still it didn't work.

```
pd.to_timedelta(new_monthly5['APPROVED LEAVES'], unit='D')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert integer series to timedelta in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519536/convert-integer-series-to-timedelta-in-pandas)

Comment: I attempted this but it did not work.

Comment: please show us a sample of your data

Comment: It is in the dataframe format but currently the picture is not getting posted.

Answer (score 1):

"Timedelta" or "Timedelta days" are not type formats. You need to convert your column to "datetime" first. Then you can use `datetime.timedelta` command to add or substract time. Use [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `unit='s'` if the integer data are unix time.

Comment: Can not convert it into date time as the column contains integer values.